# Executing the bash code in python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, I have a bash code which stores the result of the file into a variable like this:

```
variable=(`cat text`)
```

The `variable` is now has the contents of `test`. I tried similar in python using `Popen` call like this:

```
 subprocess.Popen("variable=(`cat text`)")
```

But I get error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./push-jenkins", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen("variable=(`cat text`)")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What't the point of using the shell for this? You can read files in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access bash variables from Python. Do instead:

```
variable = subprocess.check_output(['cat', 'text'])
```

I'm assuming that this command is just an example, as you can read a file from Python easy enough.

Note that the call to `check_output` receives the command as a split list of arguments, not as a single string. If you have a single string and don't want do split manually you can do:

```
variable = subprocess.check_output(['sh', '-c', command])
```

Or even better:

```
variable = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

And let the shell do the hard work.

Comment: `No such file or directory`: Why file not found error? Do he need to write full path of `text` file?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: If the text file is not found you will get a `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1. If you get `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, that's because it cannot find the executable. Make sure that the command is written properly, and if it keeps failing, update the question with your new code and the new error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with pipes here, you can do something like this:

```
import subprocess as subp

proc = subp.Popen(["python", "Test_Pipe.py"], stdout=subp.PIPE, stdin=subp.PIPE)

while True :
    data = proc.stdout.readline() #block / wait
    print data
```